# Self-flat modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, flatness

(This is inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/315869) and asked out of pure curiosity.)

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. Then, $N$ is called *$M$-flat* if whenever $M'\rightarrow M$ is a monomorphism of $R$-modules, then the induced morphism $M'\otimes_RN\rightarrow M\otimes_RN$ is a monomorphism, too. One can show that an $R$-module $N$ is flat (i.e., $M$-flat for every $M$) if and only if it is $R$-flat.

Let's call an $R$-module $M$ *self-flat* if it is $M$-flat, i.e. if whenever $M'\rightarrow M$ is a monomorphism of $R$-modules, then the induced morphism $M'\otimes_RM\rightarrow M\otimes_RM$ is a monomorphism, too.

In the aforementioned question examples were given that show that not every module is self-flat. On the other hand, it is readily checked that flat modules, <strike>injective modules,</strike> monogeneous modules, and semisimple modules are self-flat.

> What are other classes of self-flat modules?

(A quick search among the usual suspects (Lazard's *Autour de la platitude,* Bourbaki's *AC,* Lam's *Lectures on rings and modules,* etc.) did not turn up anything about this notion.)

Comment: This sounds like a fun one Fred. First toy case might be: what about $M=(x,y)$, with $R=k[[x,y]]$?

Comment: The first paragraph of the question is wrong as now written.  To correct it, the last two sentences in the first paragraph should read: "Then, $N$ is called $M$-flat if whenever $M'\to M$ is a monomorphism of $R$-modules, then the induced morphism $M'\otimes_RN\to M\otimes_RN$ is a monomorphism, too.  One can show that an $R$-module $N$ is flat (i.e., $M$-flat for every $M$) if and only if it is $R$-flat."

Comment: (With the above correction in mind.) If $M'$ is a submodule in $M$ and $N$ is $M$-flat, then $N$ is also $M'$-flat. It follows that if $R$ is a submodule in $M$ and $N$ is $M$-flat, then $N$ is flat. In particular, as $k[[x,y]]\cong xk[[x,y]]\subset (x,y)\subset k[[x,y]]$, the $k[[x,y]]$-module $M=(x,y)$ is not self-flat (since it is not flat).

Comment: Leonid: nice observation!

Comment: Obviously, one can replace $R$ by $R/ann(M)$, so we can assume $M$ is faithful. Also from that observation, flat modules over quotients of $R$ are self flat. What about the converse? Leonid's comment shows that if $R$ embeds into $M$, $M$ must be flat, so it is almost a converse.